# My cloth physics stop working when baked, what's going on and how can i fix it?

Tags: rendering, physics, baking, cloth-simulation, timeline

I'm trying to follow a towel tutorial. However my physics aren't operating correctly. Even before baking my cloth only will fall correctly when i hit play, then tab out of object mode and into edit, then back into object mode. But after baking, it stops altogether. It's a plane with denim cloth physics added, in front of a larger pane with collision on it. I got it to operate but inconsistently, it required me constantly switching between mode types. But once i baked it it stopped altogether.

Here's a link to a [video](https://imgur.com/a/yOgiSYI) of it, but why is it being wonky before baking and why does it stop completely afterwards?

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: My only reaction is that you have some extremely high setting for stiffness and damping.  Cardboard?  Try lowering stiffness to 15 (all) and Damping to 5 (all).  Otherwise both before and after baking look the same to me.  Also, and perhaps most important you have to *shake* the simulation that is stored -- try setting and unsetting "disk cache" to clear out any cache that isn't properly clearing.  And then throw salt over yer shoulder.  quirky, i know...

Answer (score 0):

Cloth simulation seems to fail if the cloth is too perpendicular to the global axis, if you rotate it slightly on Z it will work fine:

[image]